# Cannot find `MetadataProgram.PREFIX` anymore from @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata:^2.2.3

Tags: web3.js, metaplex

I have upgraded  `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata` to the latest version today (version = 2.2.3).
But I cannot find `MetadataProgram.PREFIX` any more, I know it's just a string `metadata`, but it would great if we can still keep using it as a constant.
Anyone has any idea about it?
Any comment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Currently,If you have to interact with any of the MPL program you can either use the low level SDK's which are now auto generated using Solita or you can use the JS SDK which is a high level SDK.